# Non-commutative sympify (or simplify)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy, mathematical-expressions, commutativity

I would like to be able to simplify mathematical expressions from a string in Python. 
There are several "commutative" ways of doing it. 
Is there a non-commutative function for that?

I know that *sympify* from *sympy* can do some non-commutative jobs, here you have an example:

```
from sympy import *
x=Symbol('x',commutative=False)
y=Symbol('y',commutative=False)

print sympify(3*x*y - y*x - 2*x*y)
```

it will print x*y -y*x, however if we apply sympify to the string, that is,

```
print sympify('3*x*y - y*x - 2*x*y')
```

The result is *0*.

Is there a way of simplifying the above string to preserve non-commutativity of *x* and *y*?

I found that someone has already asked about it here http://osdir.com/ml/python-sympy/2012-02/msg00250.html and someone has answered http://osdir.com/ml/python-sympy/2012-02/msg00255.html, however the solution seems not to work in general.

I preferred to ask first, if there is no immediate solution I guess that I will have to code it myself.

Comment: Ok, I wrote a code. The algorithm works as follows, first we decompose each element of our equation into a list, however if this element coincides with a letter of a defined symbol we replace this element with a symbol, we apply the same for numbers. Then we convert our list to the one in the reverse polish notation (http://andreinc.net/2010/10/05/converting-infix-to-rpn-shunting-yard-algorithm/). It is easy to evaluate an expression which is in a reverse polish notation, we can slightly modify the following code http://danishmujeeb.com/blog/2014/12/parsing-reverse-polish-notation-in-python.

Comment: Then we are done. I will write this code in a nice way and post it as an answer if someone does not come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You still need to tell Sympy that there are constraints on the symbols x and y. To do this, still create `Symbol` instances for them, and then just pass those parameters in as `locals` to `sympify`:

```
In [120]: x = sympy.Symbol('x', commutative=False)

In [121]: y = sympy.Symbol('y', commutative=False)

In [122]: sympy.sympify('3*x*y - y*x - 2*x*y', locals={'x':x, 'y':y})
Out[122]: x*y - y*x
```

To do it programmatically, SymPy provides some nice parsing tools for extracting symbols from a string expression. The key idea is that you have to *suppress evaluation* since normal evaluation will make commutativity assumptions that ruin your ability to extract what you need:

```
In [155]: s = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr('3*x*y - y*x - 2*x*y', evaluate=False)

In [156]: s.atoms(sympy.Symbol)
Out[156]: {x, y}
```

It does not appear that there is a direct way to mutate the assumption state of an already-created `Symbol`, which is unfortunate. But you can iterate through these symbols, and make a new collection of symbols with the same names and the non-commutative assumption, and use that for `locals` in `sympify`.

```
def non_commutative_sympify(expr_string):
    parsed_expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(
        expr_string, 
        evaluate=False
    )

    new_locals = {sym.name:sympy.Symbol(sym.name, commutative=False)
                  for sym in parsed_expr.atoms(sympy.Symbol)}

    return sympy.sympify(expr_string, locals=new_locals)
```

Which gives, e.g.:

```
In [184]: non_commutative_sympify('3*x*y - y*x - 2*x*y')
Out[184]: x*y - y*x

In [185]: non_commutative_sympify('x*y*z - y*z*x - 2*x*y*z + z*y*x')
Out[185]: -x*y*z - y*z*x + z*y*x
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution which I was looking for :) it is much more elegant. I was finding issue after issue in my code and it was taking some time to fix them.

Comment: I think I found a way to fully get the symbols programmatically too. I will add an update.

Comment: For that you could combine the idea in my code with the functionality of the locals and you will have to build a dict as well for all the letters.

Comment: Yes, but if you see the update, you can use `parse_expr` with the `evaluate=False` option to prevent SymPy from actually doing any simplification at all. Then, the unsimplified expression has a `atoms` function, which when given `Symbol` as the argument will return a `set` of all of the things from the expression string that will be parsed as `Symbols`. Then you don't have to build the `dict` manually, instead you can just populate it with direct, non-commutative copies of whatever `atoms` returns, as in my final examples.

Comment: Great, it looks really elegant. Thank you! I don't have to check my code anymore, I was finding issues when I tried some more complicated examples. I think that I manged to fix, but you might find still some examples which would not work with it.

Comment: I think the main point is that you should not create your own parsing implementation for this. A homemade parsing implementation is generally much less reliable than the tested parsing implementations already part of SymPy. The SymPy versions further benefit from having a wider user base, active source control and bug reporting portals, etc. There is no upside to using your own parsing code unless it is truly doing something that the SymPy implementation literally cannot do, which is not the case here (actually it's quite easy and concise to do it in SymPy).

Comment: I totally agree. Thanks to your code I made a simple noncommutative calculator (Tkinter app) which simplifies expressions and displays their LaTeX code. I uploaded the source code on GitHub https://github.com/Nty24/Noncommutative_calculator It might be useful for some algebraists who does not have a patience to use Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. For the algorithm please see either my above comments or the comments in the code. I will appreciate if someone comes with a more elegant piece of code.

```
"""
Created on Sat Aug 22 22:15:16 2015

@author: GnacikM
"""

from sympy import *
import re
import string

"""
names for variables in a list
"""
alpha = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
Alpha = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

"""
Creating symbols
"""
def symbol_commutativity(my_symbol, name, status):
    my_symbol = Symbol(str(name), commutative=status)
    return my_symbol

symbols_lower = []
for item in alpha:
    symbols_lower.append(symbol_commutativity(item, item, False))

symbols_upper = []
for item in Alpha:
    symbols_upper.append(symbol_commutativity(item, item, False))

"""
Transforming an infix expression to Reverse Polish Notation
http://andreinc.net/2010/10/05/converting-infix-to-rpn-shunting-yard-algorithm/
"""
#Associativity constants for operators
LEFT_ASSOC = 0
RIGHT_ASSOC = 1

#Supported operators
OPERATORS = {
    '+' : (0, LEFT_ASSOC),
    '-' : (0, LEFT_ASSOC),
    '*' : (5, LEFT_ASSOC),
    '/' : (5, LEFT_ASSOC),
    '%' : (5, LEFT_ASSOC),
    '^' : (10, RIGHT_ASSOC)
}

#Test if a certain token is operator
def isOperator(token):
    return token in OPERATORS.keys()

#Test the associativity type of a certain token
def isAssociative(token, assoc):
    if not isOperator(token):
        raise ValueError('Invalid token: %s' % token)
    return OPERATORS[token][1] == assoc

#Compare the precedence of two tokens
def cmpPrecedence(token1, token2):
    if not isOperator(token1) or not isOperator(token2):
        raise ValueError('Invalid tokens: %s %s' % (token1, token2))
    return OPERATORS[token1][0] - OPERATORS[token2][0]   


#Transforms an infix expression to RPN
def infixToRPN(tokens):
    out = []
    stack = []
    #For all the input tokens [S1] read the next token [S2]
    for token in tokens:
        if isOperator(token):
            # If token is an operator (x) [S3]
            while len(stack) != 0 and isOperator(stack[-1]):
                # [S4]
                if (isAssociative(token, LEFT_ASSOC) and cmpPrecedence(token, stack[-1]) <= 0) or (isAssociative(token, RIGHT_ASSOC) and cmpPrecedence(token, stack[-1]) < 0):
                    # [S5] [S6]
                    out.append(stack.pop())
                    continue
                break
            # [S7]
            stack.append(token)
        elif token == '(':
            stack.append(token) # [S8]
        elif token == ')':
            # [S9]
            while len(stack) != 0 and stack[-1] != '(':
                out.append(stack.pop()) # [S10]
            stack.pop() # [S11]
        else:
            out.append(token) # [S12]
    while len(stack) != 0:
        # [S13]
        out.append(stack.pop())
    return out

"""
Evaluating an expression in Reverse Polish Notation, an input is a list
http://danishmujeeb.com/blog/2014/12/parsing-reverse-polish-notation-in-python
"""

def parse_rpn(expression):

  stack = []

  for val in expression:
      if val in ['-', '+', '*', '/', '^']:
          op1 = stack.pop()
          if len(stack)==0:
              op2 = 0
          else:
              op2 = stack.pop()

          if val=='-': 
              result = op2 - op1
          elif val=='+': 
              result = op2 + op1
          elif val=='*': 
              result = op2 * op1
          elif val=='/': 
              result = op2 / op1
          elif val=='^':
              result =  op2 ** op1
          stack.append(result)
      else:
          stack.append(val)
  return stack

"""
Definition of my non-commutative sympify
"""
def nc_sympify(string):
    expression_list = re.findall(r"(-\number|\b\w*[\.]?\w+\b|[\(\)\+\*\-\/^])", string)

    """ Modifying expression_list to fix the issue with negative numbers """
    t = len(expression_list) 
    i=0
    while i<t:
        if len(expression_list[i])>1 and expression_list[i][0]=='-' and expression_list[i-1]!='(':
            new_list1 = expression_list[:i]
            if i<len(expression_list):
                new_list2 = expression_list[i+1:]
            else:
                new_list2 = []
            new_entry1 = expression_list[i][0]
            new_entry2 = expression_list[i][1:]
            expression_list[:] = new_list1 +[new_entry1] +[new_entry2]+new_list2 
            t = len(expression_list)
        i+=1
    """End of this modification """

    for i in xrange(len(expression_list)):
        if expression_list[i] in alpha:
            for j in range(len(alpha)):
                if expression_list[i] == alpha[j]:
                    expression_list[i] = symbols_lower[j]
        elif expression_list[i]  in Alpha:
            for k in xrange(len(Alpha)):
                if expression_list[i]  == Alpha[k]:
                    expression_list[i] = symbols_upper[k]
        elif expression_list[i]  not in ['-', '+', '*', '/', '(', ')', '^', ' ']:
            expression_list[i]  = float(expression_list[i] )
            if i>0 and expression_list[i].is_integer()==True and expression_list[i-1]!='/':
                expression_list[i]=int(expression_list[i])
            elif i==0 and expression_list[i].is_integer()==True:
                expression_list[i]=int(expression_list[i])

    output = infixToRPN(expression_list)

    return parse_rpn(output)[0]


print nc_sympify('3*x*y - y*x - 2*x*y')
```