# Problems when substituting a matrix in a polynomial

Tags: sympy

Example: let

```
M = Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]) # and 
p = Poly(x**3 + x + 1)    # then
p.subs(x,M).expand()
```

gives the error :

*TypeError: cannot add <class'sympy.matrices.immutable.ImmutableDenseMatrix'> and <class 'sympy.core.numbers.One'>*

which is very plausible since the two first terms become matrices but the last term (the constant term) is not a matrix but a scalar. To remediate to this situation I changed the polynomial to

```
p = Poly(x**3 + x + x**0)    # then
```

the same error persists. Am I obliged to type the expression by hand, replacing x by M? In this example the polynomial has only three terms but in reality I encounter (multivariate polynomials with) dozens of terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the question is mainly revolving around the concept of [Matrix polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_polynomial): [image]

(where P is a polynomial, and A is a matrix)

I think this is saying that the free term is a number, and it cannot be added with the rest which is a matrix, effectively the addition operation is undefined between those two types.

> TypeError: cannot add <class'sympy.matrices.immutable.ImmutableDenseMatrix'> and <class 'sympy.core.numbers.One'>

However, this can be circumvented by defining a function that evaluates the matrix polynomial for a specific matrix. The difference here is that we're using [matrix exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Powers_of_a_matrix), so we correctly compute the free term of the matrix polynomial `a_0 * I` where `I=A^0` is the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) of the required shape:

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
M = Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
p = Poly(x**3 + x + 1)

def eval_poly_matrix(P,A):
    res = zeros(*A.shape)
    for t in enumerate(P.all_coeffs()[::-1]):
        i, a_i = t
        res += a_i * (A**i)
    return res

eval_poly_matrix(p,M)
```

Output:

[image]

> In this example the polynomial has only three terms but in reality I encounter (multivariate polynomials with) dozens of terms.

The function `eval_poly_matrix` above can be extended to work for multivariate polynomials by using the [`.monoms()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.monoms) method [to extract monomials with nonzero coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36818131/827519), like so:

```py
from sympy import *
x,y = symbols('x y')
M = Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
p = poly( x**3 * y + x * y**2 + y )

def eval_poly_matrix(P,*M):
    res = zeros(*M[0].shape)
    for m in P.monoms():
        term = eye(*M[0].shape)
        for j in enumerate(m):
            i,e = j
            term *= M[i]**e
        res += term
    return res

eval_poly_matrix(p,M,eye(M.rows))
```

Note: Some sanity checks, edge cases handling and optimizations are possible:

1. The number of variables present in the polynomial relates to the number of matrices passed as parameters (the former should never be greater than the latter, and if it's lower than some logic needs to be present to handle that, I've only handled the case when the two are equal)
2. All matrices need to be square as per the definition of the [matrix polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_polynomial)
3. A discussion about a multivariate version of the [Horner's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) features in the [comments of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58458832/827519). This might be useful to minimize the number of matrix multiplications.
4. Handle the fact that in a Matrix polynomial `x*y` is different from `y*x` because matrix multiplication [is non-commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Non-commutativity) . Apparently poly functions in sympy [do not support](https://web.archive.org/web/20190904012146/https://peterwittek.com/generating-noncommutative-monomials-with-sympy.html) [non-commutative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32169940/827519) variables, but you can define symbols with `commutative=False` and there seems to be a way forward there

About the 4th point above, there is support for [Matrix expressions](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html) in SymPy, and that can help here:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.matrices import MatrixSymbol

A = Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
B = Matrix([[2,3],[3,4]])

X = MatrixSymbol('X',2,2)
Y = MatrixSymbol('Y',2,2)
I = eye(X.rows)

p = X**2 * Y + Y * X ** 2 + X ** 3 - I
display(p)

p = p.subs({X: A, Y: B}).doit()
display(p)
```

Output:

[image]

For more developments on this feature follow [#18555](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18555)

Comment: Although I prefer a "one line" solution, I accept this one since it solves the problem adequately, thanks.