# Sympy -- define a proper domain

Tags: sympy

I want to perform some calculations with polynomials in Sympy, such as multiplication and so on. The coefficients of these polynomials are noncommutative . It may be matrices for example. How can I set the appropriate domain in the "Sympy.Poly" class for this problem.

Comment: noncommunicable? noncommutative you mean?

Comment: have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65678536/827519), maybe that's what you want

Comment: SymPy's poly domains don't include anything that could handle this. You would have to implement the domain yourself. If the calculations are just things like multiplication you don't need to use Poly though so a domain is not needed: just use e.g. `Symbol('x', commutative=False)`.